# How do I keep content in a 2 column layout with 2 background colours inside a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, fill

I have a layout comprised of two columns that span the full width of the page. The left column is a lighter colour, the right is a darker colour. I need the text to span the container width but the backgrounds to span the full width of the page, proving far more difficult than I initially thought.

[image: Illustrated layout as it should be]

Here's my page structure, it's really simple, but it contains absolutely everything, rather than just the content. Is there any elegant way of containing the content while leaving the background to fill the page?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #ddd; height: 100%">
        ..Menu..
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color: #aaa; height: 100%">
        ..Content..
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/uv4LkgL5/1/

Comment: You need something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/uv4LkgL5/2/ ?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uv4LkgL5/5/)

Comment: This should also fix your background stopping when your content is taller than 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/uv4LkgL5/7

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height:100%` from `body, html, .container, .container-fluid` will solve your issue.

```
body, html, .container, .container-fluid {

    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uv4LkgL5/2/)

Comment: I think you have missed the point of the question. This is about extending backgrounds **sideways**.